# How to fix error : g++.exe : cannot specify -o with -c or -S and multiple compilations

Tags: c++, c

the program no run. how to fix it ( i use C-Free 4.0)
? g++.exe : cannot specify -o with -c or -S and multiple compilations

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You seem to be having trouble *compiling* this code, not *running* it. Please show us the command you use.

Comment: `-S` and `-c` don't generate anything that can be combined into a single output file so not being able to use them with `-o` when building multiple files makes sense.

Comment: [A link to some documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options)

Answer (score 0):

Can you include the entire build command that you are using?  My guess is that you are trying to compile multiple files into an executable in a single command (such as `g++ file1.cc file2.cc file3.cc -o file.exe`), but you've also got a `-c` flag in the commpilation command.

For reference, normally when you compile, two things happen.  First, source code gets turned into machine code.  Second, machine code gets linked to produce an executable.

In gcc/g++, you can compile one source file into machine code by using the `-c` flag.  You can link one (or many) machine code file(s) into an executable by using the `-o` flag.  There's a shorthand where you can compile and link all in one step using the `-o` flag (but that's generally not a good idea, because then any change to any file requires you to recompile *everything*).

As for `-S`, that's for when you want to generate assembly code from source code.  I'm guessing that's not what you are doing, though.

Here's an example, just to round it all out.  Suppose that you have files `file1.cc` and `file2.cc`, and there is a `main()` function in `file1.cc`.  Then you can create machine code like this:

```
g++ file1.cc -c
g++ file2.cc -c
```

This will result in there being two new files, file1.o and file2.o.

Next, you can link them like this:

```
g++ file1.o file2.o -o file.exe
```

This will produce `file.exe`, the final executable that you can run.

Comment: no run :#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 cout << "Hello word";
 getch();
 return 0;
 }

Comment: @TonyTran you are approaching this from the wrong direction. What we really need to see is the command line being used to build your output. The code is irrelevant at this point.

Comment: @TonyTran Perhaps part of the problem is that you don't understand how the IDE you are using is interacting with the build system?